# Where does makecert.exe store the digital certificate

Tags: encryption, cryptography, certificate, certificate-authority

I created a self-signed certificate and a client certificate using this tutorial and the makecert.exe tool:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx

However, when I go to MMC and try to import the certificate in the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities, I have no clue where to locate the .cer file.

Where does the makecert.exe tool save the certificates it creates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1, point 1

> Open a Visual Studio command prompt and browse to the location where
>   you want to save the certificate files

Is it therefore not the location you went to, upon opening the Visual Studio command prompt?

Comment: Sorry if this seemed a bit blunt =)

Comment: Oops.  I missed that part.  Thank you

Answer (score 10):

If you did what I did and just left the command prompt in c:\windows\system32 (using the x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt) you will be surprised that the file is not in c:\windows\system32 (as evidenced by doing a simple dir *.cer).

Fortunately it will be found sitting in c:\windows\SysWOW64.